# kivy windows unable to get window abort when running .py

Tags: python-2.7, runtime-error, kivy

I want to run my .py file in windows
But unfortunately it it doesn't work. I downloaded kivy portable. Run the batch, and then run my script. But got this error instead

```
E:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86>python ex3.py -

[INFO              ] [Logger      ] Record log in C:\Users\TOSHIBA\.kivy\logs\ki

vy_15-08-03_8.txt

[INFO              ] [Kivy        ] v1.9.0

[INFO              ] [Python      ] v2.7.9 (default, Dec 10 2014, 12:24:55)  [MSC

v.1500 32 bit (Intel)]

[INFO              ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_gif, img_sd

l2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer ignored)

[INFO              ] [Factory     ] 173 symbols loaded

[INFO              ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2

[INFO              ] [OSC         ] using <thread> for socket

[INFO              ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2

[CRITICAL          ] [Window      ] Unable to find any valuable Window  provider

at all!

sdl2 - RuntimeError: No matching GL pixel format available

File "E:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\kivy27\kivy\core\__init__.py", line 65, in  core_select_lib
    cls = cls()

File "E:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\kivy27\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", l ine 121, in __init__
    super(WindowSDL, self).__init__()

File "E:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\kivy27\kivy\core\window\__init__.py", line  616, in __init__
    self.create_window()

File "E:\Kivy-1.9.0-py2.7-win32-x86\kivy27\kivy\core\window\window_sdl2.py", l ine 171, in create_window
    self.fullscreen, resizable, state)

File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 80, in kivy.core.window._window
_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.setup_window (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:1542)
    self.die()

File "kivy\core\window\_window_sdl2.pyx", line 21, in kivy.core.window._window
_sdl2._WindowSDL2Storage.die (kivy\core/window\_window_sdl2.c:954)
    raise RuntimeError(<bytes> SDL_GetError())

[CRITICAL          ] [App         ] Unable to get a Window, abort.
```

I have no idea what happened. I have installed pygame in the python portable like suggested in a similar question. But it does no good. Help me

Comment: Your question title doesn't seem to have anything to do with your question.. what do you mean it doesn't run as smoothly as it should?

Comment: sorry for my confusing word. English isn't my native. It means I have problem when running my script